# почему не сохраняется в базу больше 40 получателей?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Есть сервис доставки, в нем регистрируются клиенты,  каждый клиент может добавить несколько получателей, заполнив форму у себя в кабинете.

вот таблица для Получателей:

```
CREATE TABLE x_receivers (
  id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_client bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  surname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  patronymic varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  ps_type tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'тип документа',
  ps_serial varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  ps_num varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  ps_code varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  ps_who varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  ps_when char(14) NOT NULL,
  postcode char(12) NOT NULL,
  country varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  area varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  city varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  street varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  house char(12) NOT NULL,
  room char(12) NOT NULL,
  sort tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  scan_1 varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'скан первой стр. паспорта',
  scan_2 varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'скан прописки',
  inn varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  house_korp varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  citizenship varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  b_date char(14) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Дата рождения',
  phone varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  email varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = MYISAM,
AUTO_INCREMENT = 37299,
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 341,
CHARACTER SET utf8,
CHECKSUM = 0,
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE x_receivers
ADD INDEX id_client (id_client);
```

**модель клиента** (кусок с сохранением и записью данных в базу)

```
 /**
     * Получаем сохраненные адреса покупателя
     *
     * @deprecated
     *
     * @param bool $id
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function getAddresses($id = false) {
      $user_id = $id ? (int)$id : (int)Client::get('id');

      return DB::fetch('select address from #prefix#addresses where id_client = ? order by sort asc', $user_id);
    }

    /**
     * Сохраняем паспортные данные получателей
     *
     * @param array $receivers
     */
    public static function saveReceivers(&$receivers = array()) {
      $user_id = (int)Client::get('id');

      $receivers_ids = DB::shift_array('select id from #prefix#receivers where id_client = ?', $user_id);
      $receivers_ids = $receivers_ids ? $receivers_ids : array();

      DB::execute('delete from #prefix#receivers where id_client = ?', $user_id);

      if ( $receivers ) {
        foreach( $receivers as $i => $receiver ) {

          $fields = array();
          foreach( $receiver as $key => $field ) {
            if ( $key == 'id' ) {
              // если передается id, проверяем, чтобы он ранее пренадлежал текущему пользователю;
              // т.о. защищаем подмену чужого получателя
              if ( array_search((int)$field, $receivers_ids) === false ) {
                continue;
              }
            }

            // фильтруем значение от всякого мусора
            $fields[ $key ] = "'" . preg_replace('#[^\w\d\s\-\.\,\@\/]#ui', '', $field) . "'";
          }
          $fields['sort'] = $i;

          // insert по одному, потому что у каждой записи может быть разный набор заполненных полей
          DB::execute('insert into #prefix#receivers (id_client, ' . join(', ', array_keys($fields)) . ") values ($user_id, " . join(', ', $fields) . ')');
        //  \clients\ReceiversHistory::saveItem(DB::last_id());
        }
      }

      @setcookie('receivers', count($receivers), time() + conf('General', 'session_duration'), '/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], false, true);
    }

    /**
     * Получаем данные всех получателей клиента
     *
     * @param int|bool $id
     * @param bool     $all
     *
     * @return object|bool
     */
    public static function getReceivers($id = false, $all = false) {
      $user_id = $id ? (int)$id : (int)Client::get('id');

      if ( $id && !$all ) {
        // получаем данные конкретного получателя
        return DB::single('select * from #prefix#receivers where id = ? order by sort asc', $user_id);
      }

      $receivers = DB::fetch('select * from #prefix#receivers where id_client = ? order by surname', $user_id);

    if ($receivers) {
        foreach( $receivers as $item ) {
        $item->regionid=Cities::getregionid($item->city,$item->country);
        }
    }

      @setcookie('receivers', count($receivers), time() + conf('General', 'session_duration'), '/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], false, true);

      return $receivers;
    }

    /**
     * Имеются ли у текущего пользователя получатели
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function hasReceivers() {
      if ( empty(self::getReceivers()) ) {
        return false;
      }


      return true;
    }

    /**
     * Принадлежит ли указанный получатель текущему пользователю
     *
     * @param int $receiver_id
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public static function receiverExist($receiver_id) {
      return !!DB::shift('select id from #prefix#receivers where id_client = ? and id = ? order by sort asc limit 1', Client::$user->id, (int)$receiver_id);
    }
```

Проблема возникает когда у клиента 40+ получателей, т.е если заполнить форму для 41 получателя, в базу он не попадает. Если сделать наоборот( добавить через базу напрямую), то 41 получателя будет видно. В чем может быть проблема? Что и как стоит подебажить в первую очередь?

- mariadb 10.1
- php 7.0
- elefantcms

Comment: С кодом не подскажу но по общей логике как то так. Если сразу послать кучу запросов то некоторые могут не обработаться. Поэтому стоит поставить небольшую задержку между запросами. А во вторых нужно проверять прошел ли запрос успешно и если нет то дополнительно подождать и повторить запрос.

Comment: Ни в структуре таблицы, ни в модели ограничения нет. Убедитесь, что запрос на добавление 41-го получателя доходит до MySQL (см. General Log). Получите ответ MySQL-сервера на попытку добавления 41-го получателя и процитируйте тут. Проверьте, нет ли на таблице получателей каких-либо триггеров.

Comment: из практики было заполнение таблицы 96 строк заполняет, 97ю и дальше игнорирует. по факту оказалось, что размер POST запроса превышен. все что дальше тупо обрезалось. данные на сервер уходили всей пачкой сразу.

Comment: хотя вообще наверное не `max_post_size` виноват, там все таки 8мбайт по умолчанию (хотя мне и помнится про 2). да и в случае переполнения обещают, что `$_POST` будет пустым. В любом случае, посмотрите, сколько записей у вас приходит в `$_POST` массив.

Comment: судя по тому, что у вас все предыдущие записи удаляются, то все данные тоже отправляются на сервер одним запросом. так что проверьте что в принципе пхп получает их полностью, а если нет, то копайте настройки на размер запроса.

Comment: а не, вот что было `max_input_vars=1000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по коду (удаление предыдущих записей) вы отправляете все 40 записей одновременно.
в вашей таблице 27 полей, помножив на 40 записей это будет почти 1200 переменных.

[В пхп есть опция `max_input_vars`](http://php.net/manual/ru/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars), которая устанавливает лимит на количество передаваемых переменных. Значение по умолчанию - 1000, и вы его превышаете. *(можно сделать вывод, что отправляете вы видимо 25 полей из 27, `id` автогенерируемый, а `client_id` логично заполнять на стороне сервера из сессии, а не передавать).*

> `max_input_vars` integer
>
> Сколько входных переменных может быть принято в одном запросе (ограничение накладывается на каждую из глобальных переменных `$_GET`, `$_POST` и `$_COOKIE` отдельно). Использование этой директивы снижает вероятность сбоев в случае атак с использованием хеш-коллизий. Если входных переменных больше, чем задано директивой, выбрасывается предупреждение `E_WARNING`, а все последующие переменные в запросе игнорируются.

Так что либо увеличьте лимит числа переменных, либо отправляйте данные на сервер порциями. Первый вариант, не потребует изменения кода.